# Passing data to inner functions from parent function in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I have the data in csv format as shown below, I have used lat and long data in drawing circle  but I want to pass width and height to rectangle which will be populated on clicking of circle

The problem I am facing is data is going to circle function but it is not going to the rectangle (on click of circle) (inner function)

```
DATA
district,lat,lon,width,height
andhra,19.41079,79.177427,100,200
HIMACHAL PRADESH,30.970288,76.802893,200,300  



d3.csv("newcsv.csv",function(data)
            {
                group.selectAll("circle")
                     .data(data)
                     .enter()
                     .append("circle")
                     .attr("cx",function(d)
                             {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];})
                     .attr("cy", function(d) {
                        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
                            })
                     .attr("r",5)
                     .attr("fill","red")
                     .on("click",function(d)
                        {
                         canvas.append("rect")
                                .attr("width",d.width)
                                .attr("height",d.height)
                                .attr("x",500)
                                .attr("y",500);

                        }             
                     )

            });
```

Comment: Is `canvas` an `svg` or `g` element? Assuming it is, it works...check this simplified [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/WUDMSdT8wa4Fh4NcAGb4?p=preview).

Comment: var canvas = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width",2048)
            .attr("height",2048);var group = canvas.selectAll("g")
              .data(data.features)
              .enter()
              .append("g");

Comment: svg is appended and later all the the elements are grouped to canvas

Comment: Any error messages? Do the `g` elements get created successfully?

Comment: Actually I am drawing a map and then I am plotting a circle on it. Later I am clicking the circle to generate data. Up to circle creation there is no problem but for on clicking circle function the data is not getting passed.

Comment: @nautat could you check this